# How to replace row value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, replace

My table contains some rows like below

1. Lcd - projector
2. A & A products
3. saranvana store
4. LG - television
5. IFB - fridge
6. samsung - Monitor

I want to replace space (special char) instead of - (hyphens) in all records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table
SET MyColumn = REPLACE(MyColumn, ' - ', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want but to remove the hyphen you can do this:

```
Update dbo.MyTable
Set myCol = Replace(myCol, '-', space(0))
```

Or as a `select` statement

```
Select Replace(myCol, '-', space(0))
From dbo.MyTable
```